# How can I program or encode an attendance system in gototags or any other windows Software for NFC?

Tags: nfc

I am new to programming, and just have wandered a few minutes with NFC. And I need to program an attendance management software by using the input of NFC tags in a reader for a school project. I just downloaded the Gototags Windows software for encoding, but I can adapt to any other software you know can do this task.

I’ve only been wandering around for a few minutes, and saw a tutorial.
I vaguely know there should be a way to do this through excel but I don’t even know how to open excel through the gototags app

As it is only a school project I don’t expect nothing more ambitious than a database that keeps the number of days certain person attended and showing the name of the person.

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic stuff but you need to make things clear in your mind. And since you are new to NFC AND programming, you'll be passing through a long research step.

If you intend to program your own user interface with your own features and stuff, you have to **choose a technology** to program it.

I don't know GoToTags but it seems to be a simple program to encode chips.
It writes on it and that's all it does.

There is nothing that allows you to **read a chip**, **write the results in a database** or **display them in a custom interface**. Which is what you gotta do, right ?

It appears they had an SDK for .NET but i didn't find anything else than an error 404 on their website...

Once you have your technology, you can start to search for more accurate informations on how you can do it and split the work into multiple steps.

Basically,

- The basics of this programming language
- How can i create a database and access it through my program
- How can i read a chip and 'send' the data into my program (it has to be compatible with the programming language you previously choosed).

You also gonna need some hardware. Do you have anything given or imposed by your school ?

Once you have all of this, all the work is done :

1. Read the chip data.
2. In database, access to the user related with the data you read (every chip got an unique ID, you could use this UID to 'link' each chip with the users in database)
3. Verify this is the first attendance of the day for this user
4. If so, increase by one the number of days attended in the database and/or display the new number on your software interface or whatever else you chose to give a visual feedback.

That's all. Then, if you got time, you can add several things to your program like an auto-enrollment for users and the chips. But it already fulfill your expectations for this project.

If you have any question/additional information to give, we can discuss it. I wrote this as an answer because i don't have enough space to make it a comment.